# Permission for Android strage

Tags: android, flutter, wikitude

I am capturing the screen with this code.

```
  Future<void> captureScreen() async {
    WikitudeResponse captureScreenResponse = await this.architectWidget.captureScreen(true, "");
    if(captureScreenResponse.success) {
      showSingleButtonDialog("Success", "Image saved in: " + captureScreenResponse.message, "OK");
    } else {
      if(captureScreenResponse.message.contains("permission")) {
        showDialogOpenAppSettings("Error", captureScreenResponse.message);
      }
      else {
        showSingleButtonDialog("Error", captureScreenResponse.message, "Ok");
      }
    }
  }
```

it shows error like this ,

[image]

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` written in AndroidManifest.xml and

And permission for storage is ON in Andorid setting page.

Is there anything I need to check???

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yes. On Android 10 such code will no longer work. Use a different path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the user granted the permissions. To do this you can use below sample codes

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

if (hasPermissions(context, PERMISSIONS)) {
            
     // Has permission
     // Do your staff
            
} else {

     // Don't have permission
     // You need to ask for permission here

}
```

Method to check permissions

```
public boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```